# Save data and unwind to another controller in swift

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I want to make button which save data and unwind to another controller (UITableViewController). My button is succeeded save data, but I don't make to unwind to another controller.

My button

```
@IBAction func buttonDone(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    saveText() // it is a function of save data
    [back]
}
```

A function

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: (UIStoryboardSegue!), sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "first") {
        // pass data to next view
    var backToFirst = segue.destinationViewController as FirstTableViewController
    }
}
```

I make next

```
let back = prepareForSegue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform the unwind segue to have to call `performSegueWithIdentifier("myUnwindSegueID")` from the view controller that you're unwinding from.

You also need to make sure you've set up the unwind segue in IB. Have a look at this in case you haven't: http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/10/25/ios-unwind-segues/

Comment: I made right the segue, but I don't unwind to another controller. If I use in Storyboard then data don't save

Comment: That's because **you** don't call `prepareForSegue`, which is what it looks like you're doing with a call (Don't know what's with the angle brackets though) to `back`/`prepareForSegue` in `buttonDone`. You need to call `performSegueWithIdentifier`. Hope that helps.

Comment: I made so, but navigation bar doesn't load

https://www.dropbox.com/s/l5cx4i4wfdsqmfq/Screen%20Shot%202015-04-07%20at%202.58.14%20am.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's within a navigationcontroller simply call

```
self.navigationController!.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```